# Need to analyze: Unequal variances, Factorial Completer Randomized Design

Tags: variance, nonparametric, heteroscedasticity, kruskal-wallis-test, glmm

I'm trying to analyze data that violates the assumptions of an ANOVA (homogeneity of variances), thus I think I have to conduct a non-parametric test. My study follows a factorial completely randomized design:
3 sources
4 treatments
4 replicates per treatment*source combination (replicates are equal in size)

Dependent variable is seed germination.

The Kruskal-Wallase test was suggested to me, but is there a way to do it and test for both source, treatment, and source*treatment interaction? Furthermore, can I draw pair-wise comparisons between source*treatment combinations much like Tukeys LSD would do?

Could I use PROC GLIMMIX in SAS instead? If so, what are the assumptions that need to be met for that model and how do I make sure that I'm meeting them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will give a partial answer to this question even tought it's old, as I found it while looking for assumptions tests with GLIMMIX.

No, please don't do non-parametric unless you are really desesperate.

When not following assumptions of ANOVA you can:
1-Transform your data
2-Use a different model with different assumption.

Whitout more details on the data-type, I am not sure GLIMMIX is appropriate. GLIMMIX is good when you have a poisson or negative binomial distribution, such as encountered with count data.